# pbkdf2 Who is right?

Tags: pbkdf2

I try to use PBKDF2 but each way I get a different result. Can you tell me what the problem is?

1. Node.js

```
"use strict";

const pbkdf2 = require("pbkdf2");   // npm i pbkdf2
const sha1 = require("sha1");       // npm i sha1

const y = pbkdf2.pbkdf2Sync(
    "toto",
    "toto",
    1000,
    8 * 10,
    "sha512"
)
    .slice(0, 10)
    .toString("base64")
;

console.log("y =", y);  // X7AxWzPOJiXvfg==
```

2. Online PBKDF2

https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp

`xAeOzSOt1+xNmA==`

3. Postgres

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";

SELECT encode(
    PBKDF2(
        'toto',
        'toto',
        1000,
        10,
        'sha512'
    ),
    'base64'
);

-- ybQxw9hGrIkkXA==
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is it you're trying to _do_?

Comment: I encrypt passwords in Node.js and also need to use `PBKDF2` in Postgres. It is important to get the same results for the same input, something I can't do with a simple test.

Comment: Use test vectors for testing, e.g. [here](https://github.com/brycx/Test-Vector-Generation/blob/master/PBKDF2/pbkdf2-hmac-sha2-test-vectors.md). Regarding the website: The salt must be entered Base64 encoded (then you get the same result as that of the NodeJS code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer AK X.

The link https://github.com/brycx/Test-Vector-Generation/blob/master/PBKDF2/pbkdf2-hmac-sha2-test-vectors.md was very helpful.

The function I was using in postgres was not good, this one seems to work: [PBKDF2 function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162200/pbkdf2-function-in-postgresql).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).